# REGEX: Non-conditional match

Tags: php, regex

Tried to search for an already answered question but ... couldn't find anything.
I'm trying to make a regex that will match ipv4 or ipv4:port

```
$regex_ipv4 = '((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))(?![\\d])';
$regex_integer = '(\\d+)';

$x = "123.123.123.123";
$x2 = $x . ":12345";

preg_match("/^(?<ipv4>".$regex_ipv4.")(:)(?<port>".$regex_integer.")$/is", $x, $matches1);
preg_match("/^(?<ipv4>".$regex_ipv4.")(:)(?<port>".$regex_integer.")$/is", $x2, $matches2);

print_r($matches1);
print_r($matches2);
```

returns:

```
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [0] => 123.123.123.123:12345
    [ipv4] => 123.123.123.123
    [1] => 123.123.123.123
    [2] => 123.123.123.123
    [3] => :
    [port] => 12345
    [4] => 12345
    [5] => 12345
)
```

How can I make unconditional match of `(:)(?<port>".$regex_integer.")` ?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by `unconditional match of...`?

Comment: `((:)(?<port>".$regex_integer."))?` ?

Comment: It seems the code is working, the named groups capture what you need.

Comment: I want this regex: "^(?<ipv4>".$regex_ipv4.")(:)(?<port>".$regex_integer.")$" to strictly match "ipv4" OR "ipv4:port" in one line

Comment: Try `preg_match("/^(?<ipv4>".$regex_ipv4.")(?::(?<port>".$regex_integer."))?$/", $x, $matches);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be searching for an *optional group* at the end of the pattern. It can look like:

```
^(?<ipv4>((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))(?!\d))(?::(?<port>\d+))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dO4pF0/1)

In your code, use

```
preg_match("/^(?<ipv4>".$regex_ipv4.")(?::(?<port>".$regex_integer."))?$/", $x, $matches);
```

Note that the capturing group around a `:` is redundant. `(?:` starts the non-capturing group, `)?` at the end of the regex closes the group and `?` quantifier makes the regex engine match this group 1 or 0 times.

And to clean up the regex patterns, I'd suggest to remove redundant character class with just one symbol and redundant capture groups:

```
$regex_ipv4 = "((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))(?!\\d)";
$regex_integer = "\\d+";
```

And here is a [complete PHP demo](http://ideone.com/uOKtJT):

```
$regex_ipv4 = "((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))(?!\\d)";
$regex_integer = "\\d+";

$x = "123.123.123.123";
$x2 = $x . ":12345";

preg_match("/^(?<ipv4>".$regex_ipv4.")(?::(?<port>".$regex_integer."))?$/", $x, $matches);
preg_match("/^(?<ipv4>".$regex_ipv4.")(?::(?<port>".$regex_integer."))?$/", $x2, $matches2);

print_r($matches);
print_r($matches2);
```